# safari/chrome freezes UI when running javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a HTML table that can store a lot of rows. I have an option to filter this data based on a drop down selection. All this does is matches the selection to the row and will hide or show based on this.

When the user changes the selection, a loading overlay is place on the top of the page with a spinning circle. Then the sorting function is called. Yet while the function is running it will freeze the spinning logo on the over lay after a few seconds

Heres my code:

```
 $("#selectTypeFilter").change(function(){


  setTimeout(loadingDisplay, 50);



  setTimeout(fliterList, 2000);



});

function fliterList(){

  var val = $('#selectTypeFilter').val();

  if(val == 0)
  {
    $('#employeeListTable > tbody > tr').each(function(i, row){
      $(this).show();
      console.log("step 1");
      // loadModalDataForecast();
    });

    console.log("step 2");

    sumSummary();
    $.LoadingOverlay("hide");
  }
  else
  {
    $('#employeeListTable > tbody > tr').each(function(i, row){
      // alert($(row).find('#employmentType > select :selected').text());
      if(val == $(row).find('#employmentType > select :selected').text())
      {
        $(this).show();
        // loadModalDataForecast();
        // sumSummary();
      }
      else
      {
        $(this).hide();
        // loadModalDataForecast();
        // sumSummary();
      }
            console.log("step 1");

    });
        console.log("step 2");
    sumSummary();
    $.LoadingOverlay("hide");
  }
}
```

the spinning circle spins for a few seconds before freezing

I think it to do with the number of rows as when there is only a few it works fine

any help?

Comment: Where is the sorting function?

Comment: sorry, It is the filterList function it hides and shows the row

Comment: you are using a hermetic loop in a function declaration flow. you're blocking the tthread .

Comment: How would I go about stopping it blocking the thread

Comment: @01hmyoung you can't - but if you are comfortable with iframes moving your table and the sorting script into a separate document might help.